# My htaccess Stopped Working

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using .htaccess in order to forward all image requests to a PHP script that will resize and crop the provided image before returning it to the request. Here's an example:

Let's say I want this image, the default size of which is 900x100:
    http://www.mysite.com/images/header.jpg

Well, I want it sized and cropped to 500x95. So I instead make this request:
    http://www.mysite.com/images/header_500x95.jpg

I'm using htaccess to manage this. Here's the code I'm using:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)x(.*).jpg image.php?u=$1&w=$2&h=$3 [PT,L]
```

You may be able to tell that I mean for htaccess to strip out the filename and dimensions and pass them as variables to the image.php file.

This was working up until today, when it suddenly crapped out. I'm not sure what went wrong. Any ideas?

Here is the full .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)_(.*)x(.*).jpg image.php?u=$1&w=$2&h=$3 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the request URL

```
 http://www.mysite.com/resizedimages/header_500x95.jpg
```

your rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)x(.*).jpg image.php?u=$1&w=$2&h=$3 [PT,L]
```

would actually match `resizedimages/header` as `$1`.

Change it to

```
RewriteRule /?(.*)_(.*)x(.*).jpg$ image.php?u=$1&w=$2&h=$3 [PT,L]
```

Comment: That gives the same 500 error. If I point it to a script outside of the current directory, it works. (`RewriteRule (.*)_(.*)x(.*).jpg ../system/image.php?u=$1&w=$2&h=$3 [PT,L]`) So it almost seems like it's looping for some reason.

Comment: Can you post your complete .htaccess? And, is the file in your web root folder?

Comment: Updated the question. I also fixed the 'resizedimages' text, as the images and image.php file actually reside in the same directory.

Comment: and the htaccess file? is it inside some folder?

Comment: Sorry, it's in the same folder as the images and php file.